# Excel VBA how to convert "Tuesday 24 November" to a date?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell that contains

```
Tuesday 24 November
```

How could I convert that to a date such as

```
24/11/15 ?
```

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,9999) & " 2015")
```

and format **B1** as a *Date.*

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

In *VBA:*

```
Sub dural()
   Dim v As String, d As Date

   v = Range("A1").Text
   ary = Split(v, " ")
   d = DateValue(ary(1) & " " & ary(2) & " 2015")
   MsgBox d
End Sub
```

Comment: I need this to be VBA as the title states

Comment: @totalitarian  See my **EDIT#1**